# WP8 Task<string> DownloadString

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, windows-phone-8

I want to use this class to download JSON data from rest WebServices :

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Task<string> DownloadStringTask(Uri uri)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(e.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
                }
            };

            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
```

But i dont know how to call this function.

Is there an other function used to download JSON data ?

Comment: `Is there an other function used to download JSON data` [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not possible with WP8

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: It's a good idea i have doen something with that !
How can i return string in a async function ?

Comment: `await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as simple as:

```
var uri = new Uri("example.org");
var dl = Extensions.DownloadStringAsync(uri); -- starts download
// .. do something in the meantime
Console.WriteLine(dl.Result); --- wait for the download to complete
```

You can also use the `async` and `await` c# keywords:

```
public static async void DoDownload() 
{
     var uri = new Uri("example.org");
     Console.WriteLine(await Extensions.DownloadStringAsync(uri));            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

It looks like an extension method but is not.

```
Task<string> t = Extensions.DownloadStringTask(new Uri("http://foo.com"));
string s = t.Result;
```